# save() function in mongoose not registering changes to an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I am working on an application and need to save some stuff to an array:

```
        CurrPoint = data.W1[0];
        CurrPoint += 1;
        data.W1[0] = CurrPoint;
        data.G += 1;
        data.markModified("Orgs");
        data.W1 = data.W1;
        data.save();
```

The `data.G += 1;` gets saved but not the `data.W1` part. I have tried different solutions. This is placed in my backend created with express and node
here is my schema file:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    Name: String,
    PW: String,
    email: String,
    G: Number,
    B: Number,
    M: Number,
    W1: Array,
    W2: Array,
    W3: Array
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Orgs", schema);
```

The whole findOne function:

```
  orgD.findOne(
  {
    Name: Name
  },
  (err, data) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    if (!data) {
      res.json({
        status: "404"
      });
    } else {
      var CurrPoint = 0;
      if (WAE == 3) {
        CurrPoint = data.W1[0];
        CurrPoint += 1;
        data.W1[0] = CurrPoint;
        data.G += 1;
        data.markModified("Orgs");
        data.W1 = data.W1;
        data.save();
        console.log(data.W1);
      }
```

Any ideas on how I should go about fixing this?

Comment: Show the document structure

Comment: what do you mean? I can add the findOne function